# Sutton: Reinforcement Learning - notes reference request

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Does anyone know of some notes from the book [R. S. Sutton: Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction](http://www.incompleteideas.net/book/the-book.html)? It is rather long and not very dense in information so it would be nice to have a more compressed version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly notes for Sutton's book, but the [slides for David Silver's course](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/d.silver/web/Teaching.html) has significant overlap with the book in addition to being an excellent resource for RL on its own.